April 2024 Photo Contest: Sunsets/sunrises
Note: Yes, this is late. Sorry about that y'all!
I'll be running the photo contest this month (April).
The topic is "sunrises & sunsets", meaning photos with sunrises or sunsets in them from a variety of places in the world. Feel free to ping me in chat with thoughts on the photo contest themes or if you have ideas!
Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) prior to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.
The contest will end at the end of April (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics.
Also, you can join us in chat to help us decide which topic to choose.


This picture, no-filter, was taken in January this year by my lady, Virginia, with her iPhone 14 from her window.
In the middle of the skyline of Bologna (Italy) you can see Torre Asinelli and San Luca.


This post was the highest opvoted one at the end of the month, by double that of the next highest.

@Willeke thank you, and glad if y'all appreciated :)))

There was a time when I really enjoyed taking pictures of sunsets behind rivers, so here is my first attempt on this month's photo contest.
This picture shows the sunset on Lake Ness (Loch as they say in the Highlands). The photo was taken in the ruins of the Urquhart Castle in November 2012.



Marguerite Bay, Antarctica. February 27, 2019.

Breathtaking fusion of colors during the sunset view at Oslo, Norway shot on 01-04-2024 from iPhone 12



May 2022. My wife and I, and another couple went out to the Hard Rock Hell rock festival in San Antonio. I took this pic on our way out from the hotel to the club.

There was a time when I really enjoyed taking pictures of sunsets behind rivers, so here is my second attempt on this month's photo contest.
This photo was taken on top of the Eiffel Tower in November 2011 and shows the sunset behind the Séine River (La Seine as they say in France).


Why ppl are acting like a grinch to upvote this amaaaazing picture.

Thanks man! Before I went up the Eiffel tower I read somewhere that the best time to do this is close to sunset. You can then see Paris in the day and also see it's night lights. This tip gave me this "amaaaazing" (as you said) picture. Thanks one more time!

Have you got ig?

I'm not a social-media guy. Perhaps I should, but at the moment, no.

There was a time when I really enjoyed taking pictures of sunsets behind rivers, so here is my third attempt on this month's photo contest.
This photo was taken in Bratislava, Slovak Republic in the foots of the hill where the Bratislava Castle sits. The beautiful and blue Danube river (as someone once sang, already) can be seen with the last rays of the Sun setting behind it in a winter day in February of 2012.



I took this sunset in January 2011 in Costa Rica, looking out over the Nicoya Peninsula (Wikipedia, where I've also used this photo from the grounds of La Ensenada Lodge, where we were staying.  The colours really were that good, but I used high dynamic range to get some foreground detail.

Sunset Fishing,
I took those photos long time ago (on March 29th, 2008), in Ericeira, Portugal




Almost sunset at Pari Island, part of Seribu Islands, Indonesia.
Taken on Oct 12, 2019, at 5:29 PM. Low-angle shot with LG Nexus 5.


This sunrise was a lot closer to home than my sunset.  It's taken from the top of Pen y Fan in South Wales on 15 November 2021.  I slept in my van the night before, and hiked up through rain just in time for the clouds to clear.

There are more details on both of my answers in this answer at outdoors.se, about planning sunrise/sunset photography.

+1 for the link to that excellent answer.


Manhattan, New York City. October 26, 2017.


Sunrise over the Peace Park. This photo of Nagasaki, Japan was taken in January 2019.

This was Ras id-Dawwara yesterday, at 7:17pm. It will take months before I could enjoy such a wind again!!



This was taken during a boat cruise. It's perfectly timed to end during sunset (that's how they advertise it: "boat cruise with sunset").
Natal, Brazil, August/2016.

Mmhh not much of interest on my phone, maybe more from my hard disks in the coming days.
Meanwhile, the dusk at industrial estate, guess where...in Xewkija, on my beloved island of Gozo (Malta).
Own picture, shot with Samsung phone on April 12, 2022.



Qorikancha (ruins of a 15th-century Inca temple).
Cusco, Peru, June/2015.
